# Unable to find documentation on VBScript_Regex_55

Tags: vbscript

Basically I have been reading through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx). What I am trying to find is how I can extract a specific part of a pattern in a group.

For example, let's say I want to have the following pattern for finding emails, and I want to retrieve specifically the domain of the email with the pattern: `([\w.-]+)@([\w.-]+.\w+)`.

I understand that I can use lookahead on the first group of the pattern, but then to retrieve the part of email before '@' I need to re-write same code again which isn't very DRY.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html and test it with https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for that tutorial is in french : http://cafeine.developpez.com/access/tutoriel/regexp/
Test this piece of code I've past from this link :

```
Sub testRegEx()
Dim reg As VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp
Dim Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection

' instanciation
Set reg = New VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp

reg.Pattern = "([\w.-]+)@([\w.-]+.\w+)"
Set Matches = reg.Execute("email@test.com")
For Each Match In Matches
    Debug.Print "source >>", Match.Value
    For i = 0 To Match.SubMatches.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "[$" & i + 1 & "]", Match.SubMatches(i)
    Next i
Next Match
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks scraaappy
In other words if I understand this correctly `SubMatches` Collection has all groups.